Using Variables Within & Outside awk
I am trying to use awk to detect System.debug statements in .cls files from pull requests, excluding those found within try/catch blocks using:
awk '
  BEGIN {
    IGNORECASE = 1
  }

  /try\s*{/ {
    in_try_block=1
  }

  /catch\s*\(/ {
    in_catch_block=1
  }

  /}/ {
      if (in_catch_block) {
        in_catch_block=0
      } else if (in_try_block) {
        in_try_block=0
      }
    }
  
  /System\.debug/ && !in_try_block && !in_catch_block {
    print "\033[1;31mError: System.debug found in " FILENAME ": Line " NR ": " $0 "\033[0m"
  }
' "$file"

That works well but the issue starts when I start introducing failure when sytstem.debug is detected.
I tried exit 1
/System\.debug/ && !in_try_block && !in_catch_block {
  print "\033[1;31mError: System.debug found in " FILENAME ": Line " NR ": " $0 "\033[0m"
  exit 1   
}

but it would exit and not further process system.debugs. then i introduced incremental variable such as:
/System\.debug/ && !in_try_block && !in_catch_block {
  print "\033[1;31mError: System.debug found in " FILENAME ": Line " NR ": " $0 "\033[0m"
  i++   
}
' "$file"

if [[ i -gt 0 ]]; then
   exit 1
fi

but the variable value is not reflecting.
So I am trying to find the shortest way to pass awk variables/values to the shell.
Example class would be:
    @isTest
public class GenerateDocumentTest {
    public static final String AUTH_PATH = 'Auth Path';
    public static final String SAMPLE_DATA = '{"key": "value"}';

    @TestSetup
    static void setupTestData() {
        try {
            // Insert test site
            insert new Site__c(Active__c = true, Site_Code__c = 'TestCode');

            // Insert test contact
            insert new Contact(FirstName = 'John', LastName = 'Doe', Email = 'test@example.com');

            // Insert test account
            insert new Account(Name = 'Test Account', Phone = '123456789', Email = 'account@example.com');

            // Insert test product and pricebook entry
            Product2 testProduct = new Product2(Name = 'Sample Product', IsActive = true);
            insert testProduct;

            insert new PricebookEntry(
                Product2Id = testProduct.Id,
                Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(),
                UnitPrice = 100,
                IsActive = true
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.debug('Setup error: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testDocumentGeneration() {
        try {
            System.debug('Testing document generation...');
            // Add test logic here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.assert(false, 'Test failed: ' + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


Can you show us an example of the cls file?

Also, what if your try/catch blocks look like try { if (test) { do stuff; }} catch (...) { while (test) { do other stuff; }}? Why not use a {...} level-counter like in_try_block && /{/ { try_level++ } with an associated in_try_block && /}/ { try_level-- }? Something to handle nested blocks in try/catch.

I think what you want is an END block in the awk script. It executes when the file ends, like: END { if (i > 0) exit 1 }

@DavidC.Rankin I didn't take that into consideration when writing the expression, but I'll do so on the code refactor. I currently need a solution to fail when all System Debugs are accounted for.

I am aware of that @Fravadona, I am just not aware of any methods that I can get the shell to access awk variables, so the question would be what would be a convenient way to update an incremental variable whenever system debug is found then later be passed to the shell for further processing?

Oh I forgot to mention that this is all in a processor function @Verpous, so the function receives files from a function that traverses the folder structure and do other file functions then it calls the  processor function to then process the .cls file so the END block would fail after 1 file processing I think?

@Kenruth You can consult the manual on that. There's BEGIN/END, and there's BEGINFILE/ENDFILE.

Thank you @Verpous, I believe this could be helpful, let me check it out.

awk is not shell and it'd be tight coupling (i.e. bad software) if a calling shell script could access the value of awk variables.
Instead of this:
awk '
    {
        print "foo"
        i++
    }
' file

echo "$i"

you could do this:
i=$(awk '
    {
        print "foo" >"/dev/stderr"
        i++
    }
    END { print i+0 }
' file)

echo "$i"

i.e. print messages from your awk script to 1 output stream (e.g. stderr) and the result you want to report to shell to another output stream (e.g. stdout). Then treat each streams contents however you like in shell.
A more appropriate alternative, though, might be to set/use an exit status, e.g.:
awk '
    {
        print "foo" >"/dev/stderr"
        es=1
    }
    END { exit es }
' file; i=$?

echo "$i"

I'd still print error messages to stderr either way.
The above assumes GNU awk for /dev/stderr since some aspects of the OPs code already require GNU awk (e.g. \s). With other awks replace >"/dev/stderr" with |"cat>&2".

@shelter good point. I THINK the OP is just trying to determine in the shell script if an error line was detected in the awk script or not so I changed the logic to just exit with 0 or 1 exit status.
